# How to integrate AsMock into AsUnit 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, tdd, mocking, asmock

Trying to update AsMock mocking framework to v.1.0, and use it with AsUnit 4. But in runtime get a VerifyError (1153, inacceptible override) at the line with [RunWith("asmock.integration.asunit.ASMockRunner")] metatag in the test case class. I use FlashDevelop as an IDE. Have no idea, what's wrong. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the includes line to the Flex Compiler arguments field within Eclipse/Flash Developer?

You need to include

-includes asmock.integration.asunit.ASMockRunner

see http://asmock.sourceforge.net/wiki/Installation

Comment: Sure I did. And still does not work. It only works if I use "prepare" method manually, without [RunWith] and [Mock] meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

AsUnit 4 support was added before it left beta, so it looks like the APIs have changed. I'll have a look into it. In the meantime, I'd recommend adding this as a bug to [asMock's bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=250012&atid=1126450).