# FlashDevelop ASMock integration errors

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop, asunit, asmock

I've recently been trying to use ASMock 1.0 with ASUnit4.0 (I grabbed the package with both of them together off of the ASMock website) and added both .swc components (asmock-v1.0.swc and asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc) to the lib folder of my FlashDevelop project. I then right-clicked on each of them added it to the library. Lastly, I added the "-includes asmock.integration.asunit.ASMockRunner" argument in the Project -> Properties -> Compiler Options within the "Additional Compiler Options" field.

When I build the project I receive these errors:

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockRunner)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [asunit.framework]::IRunner.

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockMetadataTools)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Reflection.

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockMetadataTools)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ReflectionVariable.

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockMetadataTools)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ReflectionVariable.

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockMetadataTools)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ReflectionVariable.

...\lib\asmock-v1.0-asunit-v4.0.swc(asmock.integration.asunit:ASMockMetadataTools)
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ReflectionMetaData.

I also forgot to add that the FlashDevelop project is an Actionscript Project.

If anyone has any idea on how to fix these errors, I'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AsUnit 4 support was added before it left beta, so it looks like the APIs have changed. I'll have a look into it. It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217051/3603) is seing something similar.